# Stuck in initramfs after reboot

Tags: boot, initramfs, uuid, module

I got that error already twice while having my laptop, and I previously were able to fix it after them google search and switching to AHCI in BIOS. However, this time it seems to be another problem because even though sata-mode is AHCI it kicks me back to initramfs.

I tried this, [How to switch from IDE to AHCI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976071/how-to-switch-from-ide-to-ahci), with the hope to not get that error in the future. After that I sadly got the error that I am now stuck on.

Original error message

[image: Original error message]

Output from `cat /proc/modules` and `ls dev`

[image: Output from cat /proc/modules and ls dev]

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So i switched from ahci away and than back and ran a secure boot. Seems to be working for now.

Comment: If you solve a problem by yourself then you should tell that in an answer (and accept it) instead of a comment so that the question does not seem to be unanswered any more.

Answer (score 0):

So i switched from ahci away and than back and ran a secure boot. Seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 0):

for whom who get this error:

```
 (initramfs) blkid
```

you are gonna see this[image]

I use kali linux so run checkdisk for its partition. You might need to check for `swap` partition too.

```
(initramfs) fsck /dev/sda2 -y
```

This will check it and when it is completed you get "FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED"

then

```
 (initramfs) reboot
```

if `reboot` command does not work

```
 (initramfs) exit
```